# iterate through two lists/columns with conditionals adding to a 3rd list/column

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, for-loop, iteration

I am doing an assignment and I am currently facing a challenge, hopefully someone will be able to help me out.
I have two columns or list(whatever suits better) that I would like to iterate to add the result to a third column. It is a Premier League dataset since 2016 [raw db](https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/soccer-predictions/), it will have conditions to set wins, loss and draws adding the points gained or not to the 3rd column/list.
Thanks

```
def pointsF(df):
x, y = list(df['score1']), list(df['score2'])
#x, y = iter(xl), iter(yl)
g = 0
r = list()

#for (i, z) in itertools.zip_longest(x, y):
for x, y in zip(x, y):
    if x == y:
        g = g +1
        r.append(g)
        next

        
    elif x > y:
        g = g+3
        r.append(g)
        next

    else:
        g = g
        r.append(g)
        next
    return r
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone comes across the same situation, here is the solution I found out to be the best!

```
cond1 = [ (dfPL['GoalsHome'] > dfPL['GoalsAway']), (dfPL['GoalsHome'] < dfPL['GoalsAway']), (dfPL['GoalsHome'] == dfPL['GoalsAway'])]


#choices result and points
cc = ['w','l','d']
ccp = [3,0,1]
dfPL['HomeResult'] = np.select(cond1, cc, default=0 )
```